# Why do I get different answers for these two algorithms in R?

Tags: r

This is quite literally the first problem in Project Euler. I created these two algorithms to solve it, but they each yield different answers. Basically, the job is to write a program that sums all the products of 3 and 5 that are under 1000.

Here is the correct one:

```
divisors<-0


for (i in 1:999){
    if ((i %% 3 == 0) || (i %% 5 == 0)){
        divisors <- divisors+i 
        }
    }
```

The answer it yields is 233168

Here is the wrong one:

```
divisors<-0

for (i in 1:999){
    if (i %% 3 == 0){
        divisors <- divisors + i
        }
    if (i %% 5 == 0){
        divisors <- divisors + i 
        }
    }
```

This gives the answer 266333

Can anyone tell me why these two give different answers? The first is correct, and obviously the simpler solution. But I want to know why the second one isn't correct.

EDIT: fudged the second answer on accident.

Comment: Note that while the first way gets you the right answer - it isn't in very good R style.  It would be much better to take advantage of vectorization.  You can do this problem in one line in R.

Comment: Exactly: For example, `sum((1:1000 %% 3 == 0) | (1:1000 %% 5 == 0))` does it in one line.

Comment: I would also suggest preallocating your vectors before you "stuff" them. On the subject, I recommend reading R inferno by P. Burns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because multiples of `15` will add `i` once in the first code sample and *twice* in the second code sample. Multiples of `15` are multiples of both `3` *and* `5`.

To make them functionally identical, the second would have to be something like:

```
divisors<-0
for (i in 1:999) {
    if (i %% 3 == 0) {
        divisors <- divisors + i
    } else {
        if (i %% 5 == 0) {
            divisors <- divisors + i 
        }
    }
}
```

But, to be honest, your first sample seems far more logical to me.

> As an aside (and moot now that you've edited it), I'm also guessing that your second output value of 26633 is a typo. Unless R wraps integers around at some point, I'd expect it to be *more* than the first example (such as the value 266333 which I get from a similar C program, so I'm assuming you accidentally left of a 3).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know R very well, but right off the bat, I see a potential problem.

In your first code block, the `if` statement is true if *either* of the conditions are true. Your second block runs the `if` statement twice if both conditions are met.

Consider the number `15`. In your first code block, the `if` statement will trigger once, but in the second, both `if` statements will trigger, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you exactly why that's incorrect, conceptually.

Take the summation of all integers to 333 and multiply is by 3, you'll get x
Take the summation of all integers to 200 and multiply it by 5, you'll get y
Take the summation of all integers to 66 and multiply it by 15, you'll get z

x + y = 266333
x + y - z = 233168

15 is divisible by both 3 and 5. You've counted all multiples of 15 twice.